# Solving DeadObjectException error thats crashing a react native app

Tags: android, react-native, react-hooks

I created a react native app on expo and it seems to work fine on Expo Go, yet on build it crashes when I click on the touchable opacity that links the main itinerary or recommendations screen to the details screen of each item. I tried to debug the issue but cant seem to find where its coming from.

This is one of the screens that crashes:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { styles } from '../styles/itinerary.style';
import { Itin } from '../models';
import { DataStore } from '@aws-amplify/datastore';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import ActivityDetailScreen from './itincard.screen';



const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const Home = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const handlePressItem = activity => {
    navigation.navigate('ActivityDetailScreen', { activity });
  };

  if (!Symbol.asyncIterator) {
    Symbol.asyncIterator = Symbol.for('Symbol.asyncIterator');
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const items = await DataStore.query(Itin);
      setData(items);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const groupedData = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const date = curr.date;
    const existingIndex = acc.findIndex(item => item.date === date);
    if (existingIndex !== -1) {
      acc[existingIndex].activities.push(curr);
    } else {
      acc.push({
        date: date,
        activities: [curr],
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

  const sortedData = groupedData.sort((a, b) => {
    const aDate = new Date(`${a.date}T00:00:00Z`);
    const bDate = new Date(`${b.date}T00:00:00Z`);
    return aDate - bDate;
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.infoContainertop}>
        <Text style={styles.topheader}>Itinerary</Text>
        <Image
          source={require('../images/mainpic2.png')}
          style={styles.image4}
        />
      </View>
      <ScrollView style={styles.content}>
        {sortedData.map((day, index) => (
          <View key={index}>
            <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>
              {new Date(day.date + 'T00:00:00').toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
                weekday: 'long',
                year: 'numeric',
                month: 'long',
                day: 'numeric',
              })}
            </Text>

            {day.activities.map((activity, index) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.activity}
                key={index}
                onPress={() => handlePressItem(activity)}
              >
                <Image
                  source={{ uri: activity.image }}
                  style={styles.activityImage}
                />
                <View style={styles.activityDetails}>
                  <Text style={styles.activityName}>{activity.name}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.activityTime}>{activity.time}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const HomeScreen = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="Itin" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ActivityDetailScreen" component={ActivityDetailScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

I tried to remove handlePressItem as well as tried to modify the routing of data.

Comment: Do you have any logs from the crash?